# Solving the Unknown in the Figure

Tags: geometry

I was asked to solve for the $\theta$ shown in the figure below.

[image]

My work:

The $\Delta FAB$ is an equilateral triangle, having interior angles of $60^o.$ I don't think $\Delta HIG$ and $\Delta DEC$ are right triangles.

So far, that's all I know. I'm confused on how to get $\theta.$ How do you get the $\theta$ above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some general advice

- Often when you are presented a problem like this, the thing that you are looking for is something that you can't get at directly.  **Be prepared to work indirectly.**  You have to make some kind of round-about argument, and determine a lot of intermediate unknowns.  In this case, you instinct to look at $\triangle GIH$ and $\triangle ECD$ was good.  That was absolutely the right thing to try!
- **Remember some basics.**  In a triangle, the angles add to $180^{\circ}$.  If two angles are complementary (i.e. they combine to make a right angle), then they add up to $90^{\circ}$.  If two angles are supplementary (i.e. they combine to make a straight line), then they add to up to make $180^{\circ}$.  The two angles opposite the congruent sides of an isosceles triangle are congruent.  Et cetera.
- **Look for relations.** Try to find figures that are congruent (or similar).  Remember the basic congruence relations for triangles (e.g. SAS, as used below).  Try to use the scaling relations of similar objects.

With that said, an argument follows, assuming that the large quadrilateral is a square.

---

Indeed, $\triangle HIG$ and $\triangle DEC$ are not right triangles.

Observe that $\angle I$ and $\angle A$ are complementary (i.e. they add up to a right angle).  But $\angle A$ measures $60^{\circ}$, and so $\angle I$ must measure $30^{\circ}$.  By similar reasoning, $\angle C$ also measures $30^{\circ}$.

By the side-angle-side congruence relation (SAS), you know that $\triangle GIH \cong \triangle ECD$.  We just argued that the middle angles are $30^{\circ}$, and from the diagram, we have that $GI = IH = EC = CD = x$.  Indeed, not only are the two triangle congruent, they are both isosceles!  This means that
$$ m\angle G = m\angle H
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
m\angle G + m\angle H + m\angle I = 180^{\circ},$$
since the angle sum of a triangle is $180^{\circ}$.  Combining these, and solving for either $m\angle G$ or $m\angle H$, we obtain
$$ m\angle G = m\angle H = 75^{\circ}.$$
By similar reasoning
$$ m\angle E = m\angle D = 75^{\circ}.$$
The two unlabeled angles are equal, as they are each the complement of an angle that is $75^{\circ}$.  Thus the two unlabeled angles each measure $15^{\circ}$.  Finally, in the unlabeled triangle, we know that the angle sum must, again, be $180^{\circ}$.  Since we know that two of the angles are $15^{\circ}$ each, we solve
$$ \theta + 15^{\circ} + 15^{\circ} = 180^{\circ}$$
in order to obtain $\theta = 150^{\circ}$.

---

If the figure is not a square, then things are slightly more complicated (though not really):

[image]

Since the quadrilateral $ABDC$ is equilateral (i.e. all four sides are of the same length), it must be a rhombus, so opposite sides are parallel.  This implies that
$$ \alpha + \beta + 120^{\circ} = 180^{\circ} $$
(make sure you understand why).  From this, it follows that
$$ \frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \beta) = 30^{\circ}.$$
Note that $\triangle EAC$ is isosceles (it has two sides that are congruent), from which it follows that the two remaining unknown angles have measure
$$ 90^{\circ} - \frac{\alpha}{2}. $$
Similarly, the two unlabeled angles in $\triangle EBD$ have measure
$$ 90^{\circ} - \frac{\beta}{2}. $$
Again using the fact that $\overline{AC} \parallel \overline{BD}$, it follows that
$$ \left( 90^{\circ} - \frac{\alpha}{2} \right) + \left( 90^{\circ} - \frac{\beta}{2} \right) + \gamma + \delta = 180^{\circ}. $$
Because this turns out to be useful, we can rearrange this to get
$$ \gamma + \delta = \frac{1}{2} (\alpha + \beta) = 30^{\circ}$$
But the angle sum of a triangle is $180^{\circ}$, and so
$$ \theta = 180^{\circ} - (\gamma + \delta) = 180^{\circ} - 30^{\circ} = 150^{\circ}.$$
Note that this is the same answer we got above, which goes to show that it is often possible to get the right answer for reasons that are not quite right.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Triangle HIG, and triangle DCE are isosceles triangles, with $\angle HIG = \angle DCE = 90^\circ - 60^\circ =  30^\circ$.

In isosceles triangles, the base angles are congruent, so $\angle IHG = \angle HGI = \dfrac{180^\circ - 30^\circ}{2} = 75^\circ.$

Similarly, for $\angle CED$ and $\angle CDE$, they too are $75^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help,ask if it will not clear
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer makes use of analytic geometry, as an alternative to other answers.

Setting a cartesian coordinate system with origin in $A$ and $x$-axis parallel to $AB$ and $y$-axis parallel to $AH$ you have:

$y_F=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}X$

$\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{X/2}{y_H-y_F}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}=\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}$

$\theta=2\arctan\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{3}}=150^\circ$